# Pass FormData Item array of object angular

Tags: c#, angular, .net-core, form-data

How can I pass FormData to api with array of obejcts inside?

i am trying like this

[image]

this is the payload of request
how can i get all items with other data i .net core c# Api?

```
public class BackgroundCheckParam
{
    public Guid EmpId { get; set; }
    public List<BackgroundChecksResults> Items { get; set; }
    public IFormFile ResultPdf { get; set; }
    public IFormFile DisclosurePdf { get; set; }
    public DateTime CompleteDate { get; set; }
}

public class BackgroundChecksResults
{
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public string Result { get; set; }
}


   public ResponseResult AddBackgroundCheck([FromForm] BackgroundCheckParam data)
    {

    }
```

All other is fine I am receiving everything but Items. Items are always 0.

Comment: Use Angular's `HttpClient`. Warning: it forces you to use RxJS which has a very steep learning curve.

Comment: already using angular's HttpClient to create the payload above. just need c# help how can i access Items as List.

Comment: It isn't working because **you're mixing JSON and `<form>` data**. This isn't ASP.NET Core's fault. You need to change your Angular/TypeScript to use ASP.NET's List FormData name values, not JSON.

Comment: that mean we can't pass Items like this in FormData?

Comment: That is correct. Either use only JSON, or only use `URLSearchParams` (`application/x-www-form-urlencoded`) bodies.

Comment: Great Thank you!.

Comment: Oh, I saw you're using `IFormFile`, that means you **need** to use `FormData` - I need to update my answer.

Comment: Please edit your question to show your Angular/TypeScript code showing how you're posting the `FormData`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- It isn't working because **you're mixing JSON and traditional `<form>` data**.

  - Some background info:

    - In "normal" HTML, without scripting or AJAX, a `<form>` can be  `POST`-submitted as either `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` or as `multipart/form-data`.

      - `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` is an almost-human-readable textual representation of every key+value pair. e.g. `key1=value1&key2=value2`.
      - `multipart/form-data` is a binary encoding. You need to use this option when posting files from an `<input type="file">`.
    - With JavaScript-initiated HTTP requests (using `fetch` or `XMLHttpRequest`) it is commonplace to POST data as JSON (`application/json`) instead of either of the 2 `<form>` encodings.

      - Angular's `HttpClient` uses `fetch` internally.
      - <sub>It would be nice if `<form>` could be used to submit JSON too, without any scripting; it doesn't, oh well.</sub>
- In your case specifically, your `Items` is a `List<...>` being represented as a JSON array in a single form item when it should be sent as multiple form items, one for each value.

  - **The solution is to represent `Items` in a way compatible with ASP.NET's form model-binding syntax**.

    - Specifically, each discrete value has its own form name, and each list element is referenced by a 0-based incremental index.
  - In your case, the keys/names for `Items` will be like:

    ```
    Items[0].Type   = "Background"
    Items[0].Result = "Pass" 
    Items[1].Type   = "Foreground"
    Items[1].Result = "Fail" 
    Items[2].Type   = "Middleground"
    Items[2].Result = "Compromise"
    ```

    - Note that ASP.NET (all versions) always require collection indexers to be 0-based and have no gaps between indexes, otherwise the `List<>` property will be `null` or empty and there won't be any warnings or errors (which is annoying).

So you should have something like this:

```
// * Use `URLSearchParams` for `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.
// * Use `FormData` for `multipart/form-data`.

const resultPdfFile = inputElement1.files[0];
const disclosurePdf = inputElement2.files[0];

const formValues = new FormData();
formValues.append( "EmpId"        , "fckgw-rhqq2-yxrkt-8tg6w-2b7q8" );
formValues.append( "ResultPdf"    , resultPdfFile );
formValues.append( "DisclosurePdf", disclosurePdf );
formValues.append( "CompleteDate" , "2021-12-01" );

for( let i = 0; i < items.length; i++ ) {
    
    const keyPrefix = "Items[" + i.toString() + "].";
    formValues.append( keyPrefix + "Type"  , items[i].type   ); // e.g. "Items[0].Type"
    formValues.append( keyPrefix + "Result", items[i].result );
}

await postRequest( formValues );
```

---

### Alternative quick-fix workaround "solution"

In your ASP.NET code, ignore the `Items` member of your `BackgroundCheckParam data` action parameter and JSON-decode `Items` from `Request.Form`:

```
public ResponseResult AddBackgroundCheck([FromForm] BackgroundCheckParam data)
{
    IReadOnlyList<BackgroundChecksResults> items;
    {
        String formList = this.Request.Form["Items"];

        items = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject< List<BackgroundChecksResults> >( formList );
    }
}
```