# Cannot bind javascript objects in FormData to send from Angular to ASP.NET Core

Tags: angular, asp.net-core

I'm trying to send a model data along with a file from angular 12 to ASP.NET Core 3.1

I'm usingFormData to append all my model data to send to WEBAPI. The issue is I'm getting all the properties perfectly and file as well but for List type data of for class type data in FormData it is binding as [object object] and on server I'm getting null for that values.

This is how i append my model to FormData

```
formData: FormData = new FormData();
let data = this.registerForm.value;
  Object.keys(this.registerForm.value).forEach(i => {

    this.formData.append(i, this.registerForm.value[i]);
  });
```

HttpCall

```
this.HttpService.postDataWithFile('TradingPartnerForm/Add', this.formData).subscribe((val: any) => { });
```

HttpService

```
postDataWithFile(url: string, formData?: FormData, params?: HttpParams) {
if (params != null) {
  this.httpOptions.params = params;
  this.httpOptions.headers = new HttpHeaders({
    'Content-Disposition': 'multipart/form-data'
  })
}
return this.http.post<any>(this.baseUrl + url, formData, this.httpOptions);
```

}

Class Model

```
    public string technicalContactName { get; set; }
    public string technicalEmail { get; set; }
    public string shipperCompanyName { get; set; }
    public string tmsName { get; set; }
    public string shipperEmail { get; set; }
    public List<DropDownModel> requestTypeDDL { get; set; }
    public IFormFile certificateUpload { get; set; }
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

I don't know where I m going wrong, any help would be appriciated.

Comment: Can you show your `registerForm` properties and how you populate them in html/angular?

Comment: @klekmek I have updated my question with that registerForm properties

Answer (score 1):

[FormData.append()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/append):
`The field's value. This can be a string or Blob (including subclasses such as File).`

```js
let value = this.registerForm.value[i]
if (typeof value == 'object' && !(value instanceof Blob)) value = JSON.stringify(value)
this.formData.append(i, value);
```

Comment: I tried this, but it's the same, at WebApi I m getting properties values perfectly but list as null

Comment: Ok, check this stackoverflow : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70241862/pass-formdata-item-array-of-object-angular `The solution is to represent Items in a way compatible with ASP.NET's form model-binding syntax.`

Comment: Yes that's what I found that I have to add it in index format. but this is getting a bit complex to handle as I have clas property in that too class property with list property as well. But doing it now.

Comment: Try the alternative workaround mentioned there, by JSON-decoding your lists (requestTypeDDL) from the `Request.Form`. When you use JSON.stringify in the frontend, it should be passed to your Request.Form in ASP.NET.

Comment: I got it done with that indexing in FormData, the solution was bit lengthy but it worked. Will try that other alternative workaround if that works too. Thanks for the help