# How append whole object to formData

Tags: asp.net, angular, typescript

I need to send image list and product data to ASP.net api via formData. I succesfully sended images but now i dont really know how to append whole object. I have seen some ways to do that in JS `JSON.stringfy(object)` or `Object.keys(object).forEach(key => formData.append(key, object[key]));`  but it doesnt works for me.

*angular http service*

```
 updateProduct(imageProductVM:ProductImageViewmodel): Observable<any> {
    const formData = new FormData()
    // imageProductVM.product ??

    for (const photo of imageProductVM.files) {
      console.log(photo)
      formData.append('files', photo)
    }
    return this.http.post(this.apiURL + '/product/', formData, {headers:{"ContentType": "multipart/form-data"}})
  }
```

*asp.net api*

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult> AddProduct([FromForm] ProductService ser)    
{            
   return Ok();
}
```

```
public class ProductService
{
   public Product? product { get; set; }

   public List<IFormFile>? files { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: check : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70241862/pass-formdata-item-array-of-object-angular `The solution is to represent your data in a way compatible with ASP.NET's form model-binding syntax.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact, I forgot to say that my product object also has nested objects. Thanks W.S for sharing the info.

[This answer helped me](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70241966/19767808)
to understand what an object should look like for ASP.net , Here's how it should look in my case:

```
product.id "*value*"
product.supplierId "*value*"
product.supplierName *value*
product.title "*value*"
product.description "*value*"
product.vendor "*value*"
product.vendorId "*value*"
product.documents[0].id *value*
product.documents[0].url 
product.documents[0].keywords 
product.attributes[0].attributeId *value*
product.attributes[0].attributeName *value*
product.attributes[0].type A
product.attributes[0].value 2
```

And then I used the following code to convert my object to a compatible view:

```
productEntriesIteration(object:object, j:number, nestedKey:string) {
    Object.entries(object).forEach(([key, value], i)=> {
      if (value) {
        if (typeof value == "string") {
          this.appendSingleField(key, nestedKey,j,value);
        }
        else if (typeof value == "number") {
          if ( Number(value) === Number(value) && Number(value) !== (Number(value) | 0)) {
            value = value.toString().replace(".", ',')
          }
          this.appendSingleField(key,nestedKey,j,value)
        }
        else if (typeof value.getMonth === 'function') {
          this.appendSingleField(key, nestedKey, j, value.toISOString())
        }
        else if (Array.isArray(value)) {
          for (let val in value) {
            if (typeof value[val] == "object") {
              this.productEntriesIteration(value[val],  Number(val), key)
            }
            else if (typeof value[val] == "number"){
              this.appendSingleField(key, nestedKey, j, value[val])
            }
            else {
              this.appendSingleField(key, nestedKey, j, value[val])
            }
          }
        } else if (typeof value == "object") {
          this.productEntriesIteration(value, -1, key)
        }
      }
    })
    return this.formData
  }


  appendSingleField(key:string, nestedKey:string, i:number, value:any) {
    if (i == null) {
      this.formData.append('product.'+key+'',value)
    } else if (i == -1) {
      this.formData.append('product.'+nestedKey+'.'+key,value)
    } else {
      this.formData.append('product.'+nestedKey+'['+i+'].'+key,value)
    }
  }
```

I hope this helps someone